# How to pass model from one action to another without using TempData in ASP.NET Core MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
  public IActionResult Index(BusinessModel business)
  {
       return View(business);
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(BusinessModel business)
  {
       var relativeUrl = "business/insert";
       var apiResponse = await PostRequest<BusinessModel, WebApiResponse<BusinessModel>>(relativeUrl, business);

       if (apiResponse.HttpStatusCode == 200)
       {
           logger.LogInformation("business detailss has been saved. ");

           business.StatusCode = 200;
           ViewBag.apiresponse = business.StatusCode;

           //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Business", BusinessResultData.Data);
           return View("Index", business);
       }
       else
       {
           logger.LogInformation("Invalid Details");

           if (apiResponse.HttpStatusCode != 400)
           {
               business.StatusCode = 500;
               return View("Index", business);
           }
           else
           {
               CheckAndAddModelStateError(apiResponse.Data.ValidationErrors);
               return RedirectToAction("Index", business);
           }
       }
   }
```

I wanted to send the data to index action from create page if I had some errors on server side, but when I send the data errors becomes null while using redirectToAction as I not want to use `TempData`.

Can you suggest any better ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both your" return RedirectToAction("Index", business);" and  Dimitris Maragkos "return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", business)); " can send the business.StatusCode, from Insert action to Index action.  "when I send the data errors becomes null " What do you mean about data errors? Could you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using `UrlHelper` like this:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", business));
```

Comment: I used that but it doesnt work while i pass the data the model becomes null while it reaches the index action

Comment: In your code you have `return RedirectToAction("Index", business);`, the code I posted is a bit different, did you try it?

Comment: yes i have tried it but it doestnt work

Comment: Try to annotate `BusinessModel` with `[FromRoute]` attribute: `IActionResult Index([FromRoute]BusinessModel business)`. Also your actions are missing HTTP verb (`[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, etc).

Comment: tried with the method but it cant get those values

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: ok ill check and update

Comment: tried but it not able to get those values

Comment: I created a simple demo, and it seems to be working correctly. You can take a look if you want. https://github.com/Jimmys20/RedirectWithParams

Answer (score 0):

When both acttions are inside of the same controller, instead of redirection I usually call an action as a function

```
return Index(business);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public Task<IActionResult> Index(BusinessModel business)
  {
       return View(business);
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(BusinessModel business)
  {
       //Stuff
       return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() => { return RedirectToAction("Index", business); });
  }
```